# Redirect Specific User

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I need to redirect a **specific user** to a **specific page**. It's a hidden page, I want only him to access that when he is logged in. I have managed to add the WordPress login on a page. I want the user to login via that.

I've tried [Peter's login redirect](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) as it is the only plugin that gives rules to a specific user.

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to supply some code to show an attempt at least to resolve your problem. Simply asking people to do the work for you will result in a stream of downvotes and no one will be willing to help.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.trickspanda.com/2014/03/auto-redirect-users-login-wordpress/

Comment: Well I love this post and it's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who replied.

got it working with below function.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

got information from above.. below is the code. added this on themes function.php.

```
function redirect_specified_user()
    {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // User 1
    $specific_user1 = "test12";
    $specific_user1_Url = "http://www.yoursite.com/anywhere/";

    // Specify Users Functions
    if ($current_user->user_login == $specific_user1)
    {
        wp_redirect( $specific_user1_Url ); exit;
    }
    }
add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_specified_user');
```